# Declaring a Temporary Variable in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

i have worked previously with SQL Server and was able to learn how to create temporary variables and use them in SQL

i used to write something like this:

```
declare @Student nvarchar(255)

select @Student = studentname from sometable where somecondition = 1

declare @teacher nvarchar(255)

select @teacher = teachername from sometable2 where somecondition >2
```

and then

```
select @student, @teacher, other columns from sometable where some condition
```

i want to do the same thing in ORACLE Database.

Please Help!

Comment: sqlplus has variables using "define" keyword and "&" as substitution (see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch5.htm#sthref1020 )

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this in SQL*Plus without using PL/SQL, you can use [substitution variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref453):

```
column studentname new_value l_studentname
select studentname from sometable where somecondition = 1;

column teachername new_value l_teachername
select teachername from sometable2 where somecondition >2;

select '&l_studentname', '&l_teachername,' other columns
from sometable where somecondition;
```

The [`new_value` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve013.htm#sthref1337) in the `column` directive automatically assigns the value from any following select to a local variable, which I've prepended with `l_` but you can call anything. You then reference that local variable in future queries with the `&` variable substitution syntax.

You can use them pretty much anywhere you'd normally have a value. e.g. in the `where` clause. Note that text values have to be enclosed in quotes, hence `'&l_studentname'`; without the quotes the *value* would be interpreted as a column name in this case, which wouldn't work.

Comment: Make sure to run it as a script (F5) in SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable say

```
SOME_VAR VARCHAR2(255);
```

Then use it in your query directly

```
SELECT DISTINCT YT.TEACHER_NAME
  INTO SOME_VAR 
  FROM YOUR_TABLE YT
WHERE YT.TEACHER_ID = 1;
```

Then you are free to use this variable, `SOME_VAR`, for further use

Of course, this will not work in a simple SQL statement, but in case you use it in a programming block, like a procedure.

Hope it helps