# How to create a temp variable in database oracle query?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Similar to programming languages, is it possible to create a temporary variable and define it a value? e.g.

```
String date = '12-MAY-12' 

Select COUNT (*) FROM TABLEX WHERE TABLE_DATE < DATE;
```

Comment: @paul, this is possible only if executed in sqlplus

Comment: @paul, but we don't know the application the op is using so to me the answer is no. It maybe supported in certain applications (sqlplus, sql developer...) each having its own syntax to declare constants

Comment: it would be database oracle developer

Comment: Check out this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529539/declaring-a-temporary-variable-in-oracle-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, it depends.

It depends on environment you use.

For example, Allround Automations PL/SQL Developer accepts sign `&` before string for variables (values of them are asked during query execution):

```
SELECT COUNT (*) 
FROM TABLEX 
WHERE TABLE_DATE < &DATE;
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are after can easily be achieved using Oracle PL/SQL. I assume you want this using  SQL only. If that's the case, here is one way you could do that:

```
WITH
  variable_table AS
  (
    SELECT
      to_date('12-MAY-2012') v_date
    FROM
      dual
  )
SELECT
  COUNT (*)
FROM
  TABLEX
WHERE
  TABLE_DATE <
  (
    SELECT
      v_date
    FROM
      variable_table
  )
```

I hope this helps